# What is happening when you enter

Tags: httpwebrequest, browser

First URL stands for Uniform Resource Locator. It will be very difficult to remember an IP address. Instead of remembering the IP addresses URL came like www.intrepidkarthi.com. Url normally contains three parts. For example http://intrepidkarthi.com/index.php. Here "http" refers to the protocol it uses. Then the server name and then the requested file name.

Here I have enlisted the flow of working mechanism behind your browser
The flow of work

- Your browser communicates with a name server to translate the server name "www.intrepidkarthi.com" into an IP Address, which it uses to connect to the server machine. * So your browser will see if it already has the appropriate IP address cached away from previous visits to the site. If not, it will make a DNS query to your DNS server (might be your router or your ISP's DNS server). DNS stands for Domain Name Server - For exapmle if you want to get karthik's phone number then you will look into your telephone directory. Likewise your computer doesn't know intrepidkarthi.com's IP address . So it looks into DNS.
- The browser then formed a connection to the server at that IP address on port 80. HTTP protocol uses port number 80
- The browser sends a GET request to the server, asking for the file "http://www.google.com/karthikeyan.htm". The webserver then returns the requested page and your browser renders it to the screen.
- The firewall will control connections to & from your computer. For the most part it will just be controlling who can connect to your computer and on what ports. For web browsing your firewall generally won't be doing a whole lot.
- Your router essentially guides your request through the network, helping the packets get from computer to computer and potentially doing some NAT (Network Address Tranlator) to translate IP addresses along the way (so your internat LAN request can be transitioned onto the wider internet and back).

I don't know what I understood is correct or not. I need to understand it completely till the hardware level at the back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. browser has no DNS cache. your operating system's tcp stack has.
2. the server name in DNS may have many IP addresses. the browsers usually choose one at random.
3. DNS is a tree. to get www.google.com, you go to google.com name service and get IP of the computer www.
4. returned HTML page is a small part of the information. In turn, it points your browser to establish many connections to other servers, to bring scripts, pictures, etc.

otherwise okay.

Comment: Most browsers actually have a small DNS cache.

Comment: Interesting.  So, you don't go to `.com`, then to `google`, then to `www`?  You just go straight to `google.com`?